# saying בריך שמיה before הוצאה

Tags: halacha, torah-service, opening-the-ark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is B'rich Shmei said while the Torah sits in the Aron, or as it's held (by whom?)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/is-brich-shmei-said-while-the-torah-sits-in-the-aron-or-as-its-held-by-whom)

I know that [the *Shaare Efrayim*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34320&st=&pgnum=284&hilite=) and *Igros Moshe* say that the congregation should start saying "*B'rich Sh'meh*" when the Torah scroll is removed from the *aron* (cabinet). Are there halachic opinions that "*B'rich Sh'meh*" should be said before (or should culminate with) the removal of the scroll from the *aron*? (Sources, please.) If not, why might so many congregations do it that way?

(I'm referring specifically to Ashkenazic congragations and halachic sources.)